# How can i do a long swipe gesture recognizer ?

Tags: swift

I set up a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to move from one view to the other by moving to the left to view n°2 and to the right to return to view n°1.

In view n°1 I only need to make a very very short gesture to the left from anywhere to go to view n°2 while in view n°2 I have to make a long gesture to the right from the left side to return to view n°1.

How could I do to have the same behavior? (a long gesture for the both views)

Comment: Hi, swipe gesture is not adjustable for length, they are standard. I find it weird that the length of the gesture varies for you to be catch, I think the problem is maybe the view where your recognizer is attached to or the direction of the recognizer.

Comment: Looks like you need something like [interactive custom transition](https://www.raywenderlich.com/322-custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions-getting-started). There you can define when transition is considered to be completed.

Comment: Hello, thank for yours helps